# spring: -boot, -core, data-mongodb, -data-commons dependencies

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongo

it appears that the GA versions of

```
spring-core
spring-data-commons
spring-data-mongodb
```

as well as the most recent release candidate of

```
spring-boot-starter-web
spring-boot-autoconfigure
```

are not compatible.

what versions of these artifacts are compatible with each other?

I have a very basic Application.java that puts two objects into a MongoDB database and then takes them out and prints them to the screen.

```
import game.acorn.entities.Entity;
import game.acorn.mRepositoryInterfaces.EntityRepository;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner{

    @Autowired
    private EntityRepository repository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        repository.deleteAll();

        repository.save(new Entity("Jack", "Skellington"));
        repository.save(new Entity("Blake", "Yarbrough"));

        System.out.println("Entities found");
        for (Entity entity : repository.findAll()){
            System.out.println(entity);
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Entity by first name 'Jack'");
        System.out.println(repository.findByFirstName("Jack"));

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Entity by first name 'Blake'");
        System.out.println(repository.findByFirstName("Blake"));
    }


}
```

When I run this application with

```
spring-core               version 4.0.2.RELEASE
spring-data-commons       version 1.5.0.RELEASE
spring-boot-starter-web   version 1.0.0.RC4
spring-data-mongodb       version 1.4.1.RELEASE
spring-boot-autoconfigure version 1.0.0.RC3
```

I end up getting a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` at

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.registerBeanDefinitions
```

which looks like

```
public void registerBeanDefinitions(AnnotationMetadata importingClassMetadata,
        final BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
    new RepositoryConfigurationDelegate(getConfigurationSource(), this.resourceLoader)
            .registerRepositoriesIn(registry, getRepositoryConfigurationExtension());
}
```

with

```
new RepositoryConfigurationDelegate(getConfigurationSource(), this.resourceLoader)
```

being the line 58. It seems that there is a discrepancy between the version I am using and spring-boot's dependency.

So I try to up version my `spring-data-commons` to `version 1.7.0.RELEASE`

and then the class becomes available but I then get a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` at

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport$1.<init>(AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:66)
```

which looks like

```
private AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource getConfigurationSource() {
        StandardAnnotationMetadata metadata = new StandardAnnotationMetadata(
                getConfiguration(), true);
        return new AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource(metadata, getAnnotation(),
                this.environment) {
            @Override
            public java.lang.Iterable<String> getBasePackages() {
                return AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.this
                        .getBasePackages();
            };
        };
    }
```

with

```
return new AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource(metadata, getAnnotation(),
            this.environment) {
```

being lines 65-66.

when I check out

```
org.springframework.data.repository.config.AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource
```

I find that the constructor

```
public AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource(AnnotationMetadata metadata, Class<? extends Annotation> annotation,
            ResourceLoader resourceLoader, Environment environment) {

        super(environment);

        Assert.notNull(metadata);
        Assert.notNull(annotation);
        Assert.notNull(resourceLoader);

        this.attributes = new AnnotationAttributes(metadata.getAnnotationAttributes(annotation.getName()));
        this.metadata = metadata;
        this.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
    }
```

expects one more argument than `AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport` in `spring-boot-autoconfigure` gives it.

So, my question is, what versions of

```
spring-core
spring-data-commons
spring-boot-starter-web
spring-data-mongodb
spring-boot-autoconfigure
```

are compatible with each other?

my pom looks like

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RC3</version>
    </parent>
  <groupId>Master-Project</groupId>
  <artifactId>Master-Project</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description>Master Project for MongoDB and Spring</description>

  <modules>
  </modules>

  <dependencies>

    <!-- Spring Stuff -->  

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RC3</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>      
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
    <!--
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.3</source>
          <target>1.1</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
            <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
            <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

When I remove the version tags on the dependencies I get the same no such method exception.

Comment: First, you have internal version mismatches. Why are you using 1.0.0.RC4 of `starter-web` and 1.0.0.RC3 of `autoconfigure`? Also, please post your project POM; it looks like you're manually overriding several versions.

Comment: +1 What he said. The only dependencies you need there are spring-boot-starter-[web,data-mongodb].  If you want the most up to date Spring Data dependencies, use a snapshot version (1.0 is coming next week probably, so snapshots are probably closer to final than RC4).

Comment: What package is the Application class located?

Comment: I updated the POM dependency to RC4 and removed the version overrides, this solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed if you use the Spring Boot dependencies pom (or the starter parent) with 1.0.0.RC5 or better.